# 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'object'

Tags: c#

When I am trying to add value to a dictionary (object type) for existing key, then I am getting below error,

**Expected Result : I want dictionary with both value "10" and "hello" for key "A"**

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
        lst.Add("A");
        lst.Add("A");

        var X = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (var a in lst)
        {
            if (X.Keys.Contains(a))
            {
                X[a].Add(10);
                //X[a] = 10;
            }
            else
            {
                X.Add(a, "hello");
            }
        }
```

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension
>   method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

What could be solution for this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do when key is present, and what when key is not present?

Comment: `X[A]` obviously returns an `object`, which doesn´t know any `Add`.

Comment: What is the result that you are expecting?

Comment: by the way, instead of `X.Keys.Contains("A")` it's better to use `X.ContainsKey("A")`.

Comment: do you want to replace the value with 10 or add 10 to its current value?

Comment: with same key "A", I want to see both values "10" and "hello"

Comment: Expected Result : I want dictionary with both value "10" and "hello" for key "A". code is update in question

Comment: For me it's not clear what you expect. Maybe you should be more specific. Do you want two entries in your dictionary? hello = 10 and A = 10?

Comment: yes, for Key "A", 2 value 10 and hello

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the type of your `Dictionary` because you want a list of values.

Could look like this

```
var X = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();

foreach (var a in lst)
{
    if (!X.Keys.Contains(a))
    {
         X[a].Add(10);
    }
    else
    {
        X.Add(a, new List<object>());
        X[a].Add("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: It can be better to use `TryGetValue` than to first search for the key inside `X` and then (when key exists) use `X[a]` to search for the key once more to also have the value returned. But that is a minor detail.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want `X` to be a dictionary whose values are *lists* of objects? Then:

```
  List<string> lst = new List<string>();
  lst.Add("A");
  lst.Add("A");

  var X = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();  // note this type

  foreach (var a in lst)
  {
    List<object> li;
    if (X.TryGetValue(a, out li))
    {
      li.Add(10);
    }
    else
    {
      X.Add(a, new List<object>(1) { "hello", });
    }
  }
```

Alternative:

```
  foreach (var a in lst)
  {
    List<object> li;
    var oldKey = X.TryGetValue(a, out li);
    if (!oldKey)
    {
      li = new List<object>(1);
      X.Add(a, li);
    }

    li.Add(oldKey ? (object)10 : "hello");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign like below

```
var X = new Dictionary<string, object>();

if (X.Keys.Contains("A"))
{
    X["A"] ="10";
}
else
{
    X.Add("A", "hello");
}
```

Comment: Expected Result : I want dictionary with both value "10" and "hello" for key "A"

Comment: Do like X["A"] = "10" + X["A"];